# Editing rows works for one listbox but not another

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have a form with two different listboxes. One for downtime data and one for production data. I can add new data and delete data via both listboxes. I can edit a selected row as well. The problem I'm running into is that after I edit and update a row for the production listbox and then enter in new data for new row it keeps putting that data in the last row I edited. If I don't edit a row then anytime I add new data it automatically goes to the next row. This doesn't happen with the downtime section, only the production section. With the downtime section everything works as it should. Attached is the workbook. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is the code to update the listbox with what was entered into the text boxes above the listbox.

```vb
Sub Prod_Submit()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long
    
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ADHData")
    
    If MainForm.txtRowNumberProd.Value = "" Then
        iRow = [Counta(ADHData!A:A)] + 1
    Else
        iRow = MainForm.txtRowNumberProd.Value
    End If
    
    
    With sh
        .Cells(iRow, 1) = MainForm.OrderA.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 2) = MainForm.StockA.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 3) = MainForm.FaceA.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 4) = MainForm.LinerA.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 5) = MainForm.WidthA.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 6) = MainForm.PrevContA.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 7) = MainForm.ContA.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 8) = MainForm.PrevGoodA.Value
        .Cells(iRow, 9) = MainForm.GoodA.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

This is my code for selecting the row that needs to be edited

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    If Select_Prod = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No row is selected.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Edit"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    MainForm.txtRowNumberProd.Value = Select_Prod + 1
    MainForm.OrderA.Value = MainForm.Production_TableA.List(MainForm.Production_TableA.ListIndex, 0)
    MainForm.StockA.Value = MainForm.Production_TableA.List(MainForm.Production_TableA.ListIndex, 1)
    MainForm.FaceA.Value = MainForm.Production_TableA.List(MainForm.Production_TableA.ListIndex, 2)
    MainForm.LinerA.Value = MainForm.Production_TableA.List(MainForm.Production_TableA.ListIndex, 3)
    MainForm.WidthA.Value = MainForm.Production_TableA.List(MainForm.Production_TableA.ListIndex, 4)
    MainForm.PrevContA.Value = MainForm.Production_TableA.List(MainForm.Production_TableA.ListIndex, 5)
    MainForm.ContA.Value = MainForm.Production_TableA.List(MainForm.Production_TableA.ListIndex, 6)
    MainForm.PrevGoodA.Value = MainForm.Production_TableA.List(MainForm.Production_TableA.ListIndex, 7)
    MainForm.GoodA.Value = MainForm.Production_TableA.List(MainForm.Production_TableA.ListIndex, 8)
    MsgBox "Please make the required changes and update the new production data.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Edit"

End Sub
```

And this is my Select_Prod Code

```
Function Select_Prod() As Long

    Dim i As Long
    
    Select_Prod = 0
    
    For i = 0 To MainForm.Production_TableA.ListCount - 1
        If MainForm.Production_TableA.Selected(i) = True Then
            Select_Prod = i + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

And my code to reset the textboxes

```
Sub Prod_Reset()

    Dim iRow As Long
    
    iRow = [Counta(ADHData!A:A)] + 1 ' idetifying the last row
    
    With MainForm
    
        MainForm.OrderA.Value = ""
        MainForm.StockA.Value = ""
        MainForm.FaceA.Value = ""
        MainForm.LinerA.Value = ""
        MainForm.WidthA.Value = ""
        MainForm.PrevContA.Value = ""
        MainForm.ContA.Value = ""
        MainForm.PrevGoodA.Value = ""
        MainForm.GoodA.Value = ""
        
        .Production_TableA.ColumnCount = 9
        .Production_TableA.ColumnHeads = True
        
        .Production_TableA.ColumnWidths = "55,55,70,71,50,106,77,69,42"
        
        If iRow > 1 Then
            .Production_TableA.RowSource = "ADHData!A2:J" & iRow
        Else
            .Production_TableA.RowSource = "ADHData!A2:J21"
        End If
        
        
    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is pretty overwhelming -- can you eliminate some (lots) of the code and still get the error?

Comment: I can try but I'm not sure what to eliminate. I have the Prod_Submit and Prod_Reset in a separate module and the code for the update button is Call Prod_Submit and Call Prod_Reset. So when the update button is pressed it calls those two codes and updates the listbox and spreadsheet.

The Edit code is run directly from the edit button. After pressing the edit button it selects the row and puts the info back into the text boxes that I use to enter.

When I make the changes the Update button is pressed running Call Prod_Submit and Call Prod_Reset

Comment: When I press the update it runs those two calls with no issue, adding each new entry in the next empty row. When I press the edit button and make the changes and hit update it changes the row that was selected. However, every time I go to add new data and it starts putting the data in the row that was changed and stops putting the new data in the next empty row.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you empty `MainForm.txtRowNumberProd`  after submitting a row.  Seems like that should happen in `Prod_Reset` ?